# What would be the output of this system given the logic?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is:

A number arrangement machine, when given a particular input rearranges it following a particular rule. Following is an illustration:

Input: 17,19,23,7,32,26,13
Step I: 24,26,30,14,39,33,20
Step II:196,256,400,16,841,529,100
Step III:55,61,73,25,100,82,43
Step IV:256,324,484,36,961,625,144
Step V:26,28,32,16,41,35,22

What would be the output if input is 52,58,70,19,103,85,49

My answer:

I have figured out the logic from input to step II which is

step I : all 7 to all numbers(eg 17+7 = 24)
Step II : subtract 10 and square all numbers ( eg 24-10 = 14, 14^2 = 196)
Step III: ???
Step IV: ???
Step 5: square root of number in step IV plus 10 (eg sqrt(256) = 16, 16+10 = 26)
Step 5 is the output.

Can anyone help me with step 3 and 4?

Thanks in advance,
Vikrant

Comment: The question does not really have an answer.

Comment: Step IV=[(Step III-7)/3]^2

Comment: Step III=(Step II)^(1/2)*3+13

Comment: please choose appropriate tags. (algebraic-number-theory) is not even related to your question

Comment: The problem with these kind of questions is that they have an infinite number of correct answers, and we cannot guess which one the person who asked the question had in mind.

Comment: Thanks @lostlife, That is what I was looking for and could not figure out.

Comment: @ArtW, sry could not figure out which tag exactly to use for this. Corrected it.

Comment: @ mrp , why would you say it has multiple answers? can you think of another way to derive the logic? Looks like there is only one.